# Layout of the page messes up when creating more than one post dynamically(using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, posts

I am using Bootstrap for my front-end and Laravel 5.2 for backend.

When I create more than one post on my profile page , the layout of the page messes up . Panels on the right side come left side , buttons at the bottom goes anywhere they feel like.

Comment: May you post the code you use ? It's hard to answer you without see the code who messed the view up. We'll need your php, html and css codes.

Comment: @AdrienLeber html code: http://laravel.io/bin/W40NK  css files http://laravel.io/bin/32l74 , http://laravel.io/bin/Oe373 ,  http://laravel.io/bin/d9oBP

Comment: Sorry, there is too much codes in this. May you post the code who generate the issue ? Nobody else here will debug all your code. Please, see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.